# Obtaining touch location for a uiscrollview touch

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, iphone-sdk-3.2

I have a uiscrollview as an element of a uiscrollviewcontroller, along with other view objects.  The image scrolls and zooms as expected, when the scrollView is the top subview.  However, I also need to get the screen location of the touch, in particular when there is no scroll action.  (I understand the location may change during a scroll, but that's not important.)  I haven't found a way to do that.  In the scrollviewcontroller implementation I have customized all of the standard methods that should do this: "touchesShouldBegin...", "touchesBegan:...", "touchesEnded:...", and so on.  As far as I can tell, none of these are being called during a touch event when the scrollView is the top subview.  I've tried setting the delayContentTouches property to both YES and NO, and that doesn't seem to make a difference.

As an alternative, I've tried putting a UIView as the top subview and then tried passing the touches to the now underlying scrollView.  In this configuration, the standard methods are called and I can get the touch location, but I haven't found a mechanism for the touches to be passed to the scrollView so scrolling occurs.  Doing something like sending the touch messages to the specific scrollView, or to "super" or just sending them to nextResponder doesn't do it.  It seems I can make the scroll work or find the location of the touch but not both, depending on what the "top" subview is.

I suspect this is trivial, but after two weeks of struggling, it's time to eat my embarrassment for not being able to do this seemingly simplest of things.  I've read all of the related questions here on stackoverflow, tried most if not all of the suggestions, and so far, nothing has worked.  I've looked through the various links and references suggested by the answers, including Apple's documentation, but none have pointed out the gap in my understanding.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tryed using a delegate to pass the touch info from the uiscrollview to the underlying uiview?

Comment: Not multiple delegates, yet.  The uiscrollview does have a delegate, and that's where all of the methods to intercept the touches are.  However, I'm pretty sure I don't have this part of it architected as well as it could be.  I'll make another pass and consider using multiple delegates.  Thanks